# How to pass additional data to a function that adds things to an object?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, formik

I am trying to create a user profile document for regular users and for merchants on Firebase. I am trying to add additional to data this document when a merchant signs up, but haven't succeeded. The difference is that merchants are supposed to have a `roles` array with their roles. If this is not the right approach to deal with differentiating users, I'd also be happy to hear what's best practice.

My `userService` file

```
async createUserProfileDocument(user, additionalData) {
    console.log('additionalData: ', additionalData) //always undefined
    if (!user) return
    const userRef = this.firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`)
    const snapshot = await userRef.get()
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
      const { displayName, email } = user
      try {
        await userRef.set({
          displayName,
          email,
          ...additionalData,
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error creating user: ', error)
      }
    }
    return this.getUserDocument(user.uid)
  }

  async getUserDocument(uid) {
    if (!uid) return null
    try {
      const userDocument = await this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
      return { uid, ...userDocument.data() }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error getting user document: ', error)
    }
  }
```

This is what happens when the user signs up as a merchant in the `RegisterMerchant` component:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        async function writeToFirebase() {
          //I can't pass the 'roles' array as additionalData
          userService.createUserProfileDocument(values.user, { roles: ['businessOnwer'] })          
          authService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.user.email, values.user.password)
          await merchantsPendingApprovalService.collection().add(values)
        }
        writeToFirebase()
```

I am afraid this might have something to do with `onAuthStateChange`, which could be running before the above and not passing any `additionalData`? This is in the `Middleware`, where I control all of the routes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    authService.onAuthStateChanged(async function (userAuth) {
      if (userAuth) {
        //is the below running before the file above and not passing any additional data?
        const user = await userService.createUserProfileDocument(userAuth) //this should return the already created document?
        //** do logic here depending on whether user is businessOwner or not
        setUserObject(user)
      } else {
        console.log('no one signed in')
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

Comment: As far as I can see, createUserProfileDocument doesn't return anything useful at all.  There is literally no return statement in it, other than the one when `user` is falsy.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have fixed the code to show the completed thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `onCreate` callback function which is invoked when user is authenticated.

**Here's how you could implement it**

```js
const onSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {

  const { user: {email, password} } = values;
  const additionalData = { roles: ['businessOnwer'] };

  auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
      const { uid, displayName, email } = user;

      this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).set({
            displayName,
            email,
            ...additionalData
      });
  });

  authService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

Comment: 1. should I get rid of ```createUserProfileDocument```? 2. Should this be inside of the onSubmit? I don't quite get where ```auth.user().onCreate....``` should be placed exactly

Comment: You can place in `onSubmit` function or move the logic to cloud function. The `createUserProfileDocument` function can be changed to `createUserProfile` and use it as a wrapper for `this.firestore.doc...` function.